# Thymeleaf empty value check

Tags: java, email, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf template to send email. I have a template like:

```
My name is ${name}
```

If `name` is empty or `null`, I don't want to send the email. Is there any Thymeleaf property that I can set which will generate an error and won't send the mail? Because sending "My name is " in an email without the value won't make any sense.

I am getting all the values from the Thymeleaf context and the variables could be of a different type like `List`, `Map`, etc.  I have tried the following too, but it doesn't solve my problem since an object is always available:

```
HashMap<String,Object> allVar = ctx.getVariables();
boolean isVAlid;

for(HashMap.Entry<String, Object> entry : allVar.entrySet()){
    logger.info("[ESUB2.0] key and Value" + entry.getKey() + "Value" + entry.getValue());
    if(entry.getValue()==null){
       logger.info("[ESUB2.0] Null check ")
       isVAlid = true
    }
}
```

Comment: When you set the value of `name`, on the `ctx`, couldn't you just generate your error and skip the code to send the email if it is null?  Like `if (StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) { log.error("Null name"); return; }`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, just replace `isVAlid = true` by `isVAlid = false` since if a value is null, it's not valid :

```
HashMap<String,Object> allVar = ctx.getVariables();
boolean isVAlid;
for(HashMap.Entry<String, Object> entry : allVar.entrySet()){
    logger.info("[ESUB2.0] key and Value" + entry.getKey() + "Value" + entry.getValue());
    if(entry.getValue()==null){
        logger.info("[ESUB2.0] Null check ");
        isVAlid = false;
    }
}
```

Replace `entry.getValue()==null` by `StringUtils.isEmpty()` of `org.apache.commons.lang` for empty (`""`) and `null` Strings

Comment: Thanks Sebastien.. I did that while debugging. Just wished there could be a better way to do this..